# Trying to make sure my credentials for Sendgrid with my API Key allows me access to send. message: Permission denied, wrong credentials

Tags: php, laravel, email, sendgrid

I believe I'm overlooking something when it comes to the areas where I would enter my API key and/or other fields I changed for this package from github, s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver (https://github.com/s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver). I've used the exact same API on another project and I'm pretty sure it's legit. I am also new to Laravel & Php, and I 'm hoping someone could see my mistake on one of the files I edited while going down the step for installing.
I get this exact ***error***

> Client error: `POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send` resulted in
> a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"errors":[{"message":"Permission
> denied, wrong credentials","field":null,"help":null}]}

```
APP_NAME=bensonbraceletsAPI
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:DtZBELx11fpEq7ZnEUyBgg6nqxY/fpdaU468HBUpAVg=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://bensonbraceletsAPI.test

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

MAIL_DRIVER=sendgrid
SENDGRID_API_KEY=MY_API_KEY_WAS_REMOVED

MAIL_MAILER=sendgrid
MAIL_MAILER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=justkeithcarr@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=SendEmailFromSendgrid
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=justkeithcarr@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

> services.php Below

```
'sendgrid' => [
    'api_key' => env('SENDGRID_API_KEY'),
],
```